# print out a large number of integers rapidly in C

Tags: c, performance, output

I have to print 1,000,000 four digit numbers. I used `printf` for this purpose

```
 for(i=0;i<1000000;i++)
 { 
     printf("%d\n", students[i]);
 }
```

and it turns out to be too slow.Is there a faster way so that I can print it.

Comment: What is fast enough?  It may be a limitation of your terminal and refresh rate.

Comment: I can print it to file too.

Comment: As I understand it, `printf` is pretty slow - try replacing it with a different output function.

Comment: @self. `write()` or `fwrite()` ?

Comment: What do you intend to do with the numbers once dumped to file? Do you control the parser at the other end? If so I would consider dumping the numbers in binary instead.

Comment: @doynax: This has the look of a homework problem to me - what are the odds that there are exactly 1000000 students? As such, I don't think he's doing anything with the numbers.

Comment: @user1618143: Remote I suppose. I would prefer to pretend that the OP has correctly isolated a bottleneck and written up a minimal example demonstrating the issue though, if nothing else we might get some clarification on the parameters of the exercise.

Comment: i have to perform this task->1.given an array say of n=1000000 elements, input all of them 2. do a certain no. of operations on them 3. and finally print the output.. and for this program has to take time less than a second... I found a way of faster inputs , just wanted to get through the process of ouputting it fast.

Comment: What a silly task -- is anyone going to read your one million numbers? `fprintf` to `dev/null` and be done with it.

Comment: @Jongware: Homework problems tend to be silly, but I doubt he'd get full credit that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an array, fill it with output data and then print out that array at once. Or if there is memory problem, just break that array to smaller chunks and print them one by one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my attempt replacing printf and stdio stream buffering with straightforward special-case code:

```
int print_numbers(const char *filename, const unsigned int *input, size_t len) {
    enum {
        // Maximum digits per number. The input numbers must not be greater
        // than this!
#       if 1
        DIGITS = 4,
#       else
        // Alternative safe upper bound on the digits per integer
        // (log10(2) < 28/93)
        DIGITS = sizeof *input * CHAR_BIT * 28UL + 92 / 93,
#       endif
        // Maximum lines to be held in the buffer. Tune this to your system,
        // though something on the order of 32 kB should be reasonable
        LINES = 5000
    };

    // Write the output in binary to avoid extra processing by the CRT. If necessary
    // add the expected "\r\n" line endings or whatever else is required for the
    // platform manually.
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if(!file)
        return EOF;

    // Disable automatic file buffering in favor of our own
    setbuf(file, NULL);

    while(len) {
        // Set up a write pointer for a buffer going back-to-front. This
        // simplifies the reverse order of digit extraction
        char buffer[(DIGITS + 1 /* for the newline */) * LINES];
        char *tail = &buffer[sizeof buffer];
        char *head = tail;
        // Grab the largest set of lines still remaining to be printed which
        // will safely fit in our buffer
        size_t chunk = len > LINES ? LINES : len;
        const unsigned int *input_chunk;
        len -= chunk;
        input += chunk;
        input_chunk = input;

        do {
            // Convert the each number by extracting least-significant digits
            // until all have been printed.
            unsigned int number = *--input_chunk;
            *--head = '\n';
            do {
#               if 1
                char digit = '0' + number % 10;
                number /= 10;
#               else
                // Alternative in case the compiler is unable to merge the
                // division/modulo and perform reciprocal multiplication
                char digit = '0' + number;
                number = number * 0xCCCDUL >> 19;
                digit -= number * 10;
#               endif
                *--head = digit;
            } while(number);
        } while(--chunk);

        // Dump everything written to the present buffer
        fwrite(head, tail - head, 1, file);
    }

    return fclose(file);
}
```

I fear this won't buy you much more than a fairly small constant factor over your original (by avoiding some printf format parsing, per-character buffering, locale handling, multithreading locks, etc.)

Beyond this you may want to consider processing the input and writing the output on-the-fly instead of reading /processing/writing as separate stages. Of course whether or not this is possible depends entirely on the operation to be performed.

Oh, and don't forget to enable compiler optimizations when building the application. A run through with a profiler couldn't hurt either.